# Selected Index undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a option field and onChange, I call a function, but the parameter is null

#### Markup

```
<select name="estado" id="estado" onchange="setCidade(this.SelectedIndex)">
    <option name="BR" value="BR">Barueri</option>
    <option name="BH" value="BH">Belo Horizonte</option>
    <option name="BS" value="BS">Brasilia</option>
    <option name="CP" value="CP">Campinas</option>
    <option name="CU" value="CU">Cuiaba</option>
    <option name="CT" value="CT">Curitiba</option>
    <option name="DI" value="DI">Diadema</option>
    <option  value="DQ">Duque de Caxias</option>
    <option value="FL">Florianopolis</option>
    <option value="FO">Fortaleza</option>
    <option value="GO">Goiania</option>
    <option value="GU">Guarulhos</option>
    <option value="PA">Porto Alegre</option>
    <option value="OS">Osasco</option>
    <option value="RE">Recife</option>
    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="SS">Salvador</option>
    <option value="SA">Santo Andre</option>
    <option value="SB">São Bernardo do Campo</option>
    <option value="SC">São Caetano do Sul</option>
    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="VI">Vitória</option>
</select>
```

#### Javascript

```
function setCidade (indiceSelecionado) {
    alert(indiceSelecionado);//the alert show "undefined"
    indexCidade = indiceSelecionado;
    mudarCidade();
}
```

Comment: Javascript is a case-sensitive language. Try `selectedIndex` instead of `SelectedIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
SelectedIndex
```

with

```
selectedIndex
```

The first "s" is lowercase.